# how to get return type of map & only give S

Tags: typescript

how to get return type of map & **only give S**.
how to get return type of map & **only give S**.
how to get return type of map & **only give S**.
how to get return type of map & **only give S**.
how to get return type of map & **only give S**.

```js
const state = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

type StateValue = typeof state

type Getter<S, R, R1> = {
  map: (state: S) => R
  mapB?: (state: S) => R1
  // more ...
}

function getter<S extends Getter<any, any, any>>(
  a: S
): ReturnType<S['map']> & ReturnType<S['mapB']> {
  return {
    ...a.map(state),
    ...a.mapB?.(state)
    // more ...
  }
}

// to much type
const v = getter({
  map: (state: StateValue) => ({
    a: state.a
  }),
  mapB: (state: StateValue) => ({
    b: state.b
  })
  // more map ...
})

// want!! // state will be <{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 1 }>
const v = getter<StateValue>({
  map: (state) => ({
    a: state.a,
    c: state.a
  }),
  mapB: (state) => ({
    b: state.b
  })
})
```

Comment: Repeating what you say doesn't help us understand what you want. Please elabore on it a bit more. Do you want to infer the `R` parameter of a type? What does `.map(1 as any)` supposed to do (it won't work once you run it)?

Comment: Partial inference does not exist in TS (you can't specify some type parameters and have others inferred). You could use function currying https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hzAgJwDwGUA0UBKA+KAvFAN4BQUFUAtgIZgBcUAFAM7A2KNoCUh+2pAL6lSAelFQAFgHsA7lGDSoAc3hQk8AK5IAdgvDRpAM2p0oAMijSdAGxAqAlgDdoaUkc06AxsAfWV8IioaLhMvGSU6lq6UB7evv4o2IRQNDogoTSMcAjI6Fh44eSRlBrA2no0AHS0YEwAjKksqencxRTCwqRe1mxQTimquajEqYyNgqHcTBGUtYys7Ii8BPgz7SUARoxsHBBVNBuCbcdAA

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Updated again in response to updated question

You should accept the state as an additional parameter to `getter`, rather than relying on [closing over it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgAoEMBOKC2BnKEAewEcAJrmhCiQPZwA2IUKcIA2gLpQC8UFVtDJiw4AaKACUI2AK51g3ISAB83AFBQoACgB0usOizYAXFFQYcASm4rJMuQG5Vq0JFhwAsijAIAyip6SAMbUaCQI2MBoAJZwAOZi8AisEShEJj7sSkqOqiQQgXTo0ABm0nCBwFG0ULEQwERovmIAKniExGRunt5+SpopaVA+YpheJs0WJgDe6lCsANJQMVAA1hAg1MVQzewmksDSaHDN4BAIzQuZjgC+OcFwEVAD0DxTTCYAjGIARiYATFBbs5TkNgKkXlAXBBNk8wUQ7rRHqVypVEQoZhpRmAAIImfpwiDpAlWLgqTRvFAmZ7aFCAiwiWZYgBCeOeRPBJLJb1+sPB2m+dIZQNU90eADcFLV6hA0PjwWJkRUqg8LDkxfYoAB6TVQN5Y3G6ylQODSTDfGW3KDM6Y8k1mi0a66qIA)

```ts
type Fn<Params extends readonly any[] = readonly any[], Result = any> =
  (...params: Params) => Result;

type FnMap<S> = Record<string, Fn<[state: S]>>;

declare function getter<S, T extends FnMap<S>>(state: S, map: T): {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]>;
};

const state = { a: 1, b: 2 };
type State = typeof state;

const functions = {
  mapA: (state: State) => ({ a: state.a }),
  mapB: (state: State) => ({ b: state.b }),
};

const v = getter(state, functions);

v; // { mapA: {a: number}; mapB: {b: number}; }
```

---

Edit: Updated in response to updated question

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgdgHgAoEMBOKC2BnKEAewEcAJrmhCiQPZwA2IUKcIA2gLpQC8UFVtDJiw4AaKACUI2AK51g3ISAB83AFBQoACgB0usOizYAXFFQYcASm4rJMuQG5Vq0JFhwAsijALJAY2poJAjYwGgAlnAA5mLwSo6qJBC+dOjQAGbScL7AYbRQkRDARGgIACp4hMRkbp5gYgDSFUSkuADWECDUaVClSpqYXialYu0gJvUWJpLA0mhwpeAQZaz17HFO-nAhUBlZObS4PADe6lADYACMJpohKEQmR0wmcNKYAEYQaFAAvlZcKppHm8TLciNoUD8LCJTucAEzXUEQB5QYFQELhKKQ6xaR6+EHAO4QbRvSHQ77xTbbABuCgKRU+ml22VyWzEAHJzhc2RZ4lT7FAAPQCqBA56vD5fb5AA)

```ts
type Fn<Params extends readonly any[] = readonly any[], Result = any> =
  (...params: Params) => Result;

type FnMap = Record<string, Fn>;

declare function getter<T extends FnMap, K extends keyof T>(map: T, key: K): ReturnType<T[K]>;

const functions = {
  map1: (state: { a: number }) => ({ b: state.a }),
  map2: (state: { b: string }) => ({ c: state.b }),
};

const v = getter(functions, 'map1');

v; // { b: number }
```

---

You can do it completely with inference. Just move the generic type you were supplying for `S` from `getter` to the `state` parameter in your `map` method:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hzAgJwDwGUA0UBKA+KAvFAN4BQUUAtgIZgBcUAFAM7DWINoCUh+2A3KQC+g0gBMIAYwA21JNABmAVwB2k4AEsA9iqgBzeIlQAVKBAAeiFWOaxDyFNRUgsTkLlyMAbtWlKIDMZcDNjwSkgqxuAQKMYA2gDkNGAJALq4opI6rFBehPr2SIxkFMkMLGwcJFDUDCpKlABGyFBCPAT4xVCNDKzsEAB01K1cGMJcol78UAD0M9U9UPVNLUJAA)

```ts
type Getter<S, R> = {
  map: (state: S) => R;
};

declare function getter<T extends Getter<any, any>>(value: T): ReturnType<T['map']>;

const v = getter({
  map: (state: { a: number }) => ({ b: state.a }),
});

v; // { b: number }
```

Comment: thinks! but i want 
```typescript
const v = getter<{ a: number }>({
  map: (state ) => ({ b: state.a }),
// because here have more map
mapxxx: ( state ) => ({ b: state.a }),
});
```

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: There seems to be no difference between the two
`map` is written by users, and many types still need to be written.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with an actual example of usage. The current one doesn't seem to represent the real problem you're describing.

Comment: So, your `getter` _always_ returns the result of invoking `a.map`? (That's what the question indicates.)

Comment: `ReturnType<S['map']> & ReturnType<S['mapB']>` it return fn's ReturnType

Comment: @user9699002 In your question, it only shows returning the return value of `a.map`.

Comment: question code updated :)

Comment: @user9699002 See my updated answer